# Android server can't be reached from device

Tags: android

I am trying to access some php files that get data out of a local database.

The url is http://192.168.x.x/Foodlogging/getUserFromDB.php.

This worked perfectly in the emulator when I used 10.0.2.2.

I can access this url from my browser on my computer itself but not from the browser on the device.

I have this inside my manifest:     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`.

Both the devices are on the same network.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

P.S.: I am on my schools network and I know they have very strict firewall rules/settings, so might that be the problem? Like 1/100 I can access the url, the other times I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the mobile internet on the android phone, and leave Wifi on only.
This caused some issues for me when accessing local lan servers (usually 192.168.x.x).

Comment: There is no sim-card in the device so the mobile internet should be off (just checked it, it's off). Like 1/100 I can access the url, the other times I can't.